# Remove all substrings between angle brackets

Tags: r, regex, gsub

In the following string

```
test_string = "This is a te<8239154>st str<ass31>ing."
```

I would like to replace all occurences of the form `<xxx>` with an empty string.

I know that I can use `gsub("<8239154>", "", "test_string ")` but this cannot be applied dynamically to any string which is in between the comparison signs. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
gsub("<[^>]*>", "", test_string)
gsub("<[^<>]*>", "", test_string)
```

The `<[^>]*>` regex matches `<`, then any zero or more chars other than `>` and then it matches a `>` char. The `<[^<>]*>` pattern is similar except that it does not allow `<` in between `<` and `>` (this can be handy to remove *innermost* occurrences of `<` and `>`).

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KWWeYq/1).

Note that in case you need to remove only word chars enclosed with `<` and `>` symbols, you can use a more specific solution, namely

```r
gsub("<\\w+>", "", test_string)
```

where `\w+` matches one or more letter, digits or underscores. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KWWeYq/2).