# Remove illegal character

Tags: r

In a dataframe frame like this:

```
data.frame(term = c("clear text","character <U+C6C3>","<e9>guret text"))
```

Is there any command which could provide the removal of the character inside the <>

Example output:

```
data.frame(term = c("clear text","character","guret text"))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68313671/5325862

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple usage of `gsub` and `trimws`.

```
data <- data.frame(term = c("clear text", "character <U+C6C3>", "<e9>guret text"))
data$term <- trimws(gsub("<.*>", "", data$term))
```